# .gitattributes file - prevent file from being merged but still view diff

Tags: git, git-merge, gitk, gitattributes

I'm dealing with some really awkward XML files that I want to prevent being merged. I know that I can do this using the `-diff` marker in .gitattributes. However I would still like to be able to read the diff in gitk if possible.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this isn't possible, as using the `-diff` marker is a bit of a hack in the first place, to stop git trying to do merges (rather than actually wanting to block diff's themselves)

However, the workaround is to use an external diff program, such as KDiff3.